# release build but debug gives an error

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, build

I have a strange problem.

Building a debug version gives an error but release build does not.

All (build) settings are the same!

I am using vc++ in vs2012 ultimate

If I build the project alone the same problem appears.

Does some one  have a suggestion??

cheers

Hans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ***differences*** between **Rlease** and **Debug**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa236698%28v=vs.60%29.aspx, [Best practices and tools for debugging differences between Debug and Release builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090968/best-practices-and-tools-for-debugging-differences-between-debug-and-release-bui) and [Differences that may occur between Debug and Release builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688145/differences-that-may-occur-between-debug-and-release-builds).

From my experience, the common mistake are usual caused by uninitialized parameters. In **Debug** mode, the parameters might initialized as zeros. While in **Release** mode, it might be uninitialized.

You might have to check your code to make sure **every parameters is initialized.**

*BTW: The compiler will give some useful informations, please read them carefully.*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for thinking with me!!

I removed an added header file and it was solved.
This header file was not needed!

Thanks any way!!

Cheers
Hans